# How to optimise join query with geom

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I want to do a join on two tables with table b row is null, then insert into another table for further analysis.

I am using the following join:

```
SELECT a.*
INTO tmp_missing_cad_polygon
FROM table_a a
LEFT JOIN table_b b
    ON a.geom = b.geom
WHERE b.geom IS NULL;
```

This query seems to work well on small data sets, but not on larger sets. I have tried nested select statement on the geom, but doesn't seem to work with geom data structures.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, for spatial joins, it is recommended to use the EXCEPT clause for large datasets.

```
SELECT a.cad_pid FROM left_table a
EXCEPT
SELECT b.cad_pid FROM right_table b;
```

This only returns rows from the left table that do not match the right table. Deeper analysis can be found in the provided links.

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/the-except-and-intersect-operators-in-sql-server/
https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sqlserver-18-how-to-use-the-except-operator/